# How to Convert itextsharp document to byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, itext, pdf-generation

I am trying to merge two `PDF` in this method but after successfully adding, I am unable to convert `iTextSharp.text.Document` into `byte` array . Please help me.

```
protected byte[] MergePDFs(byte[] First, byte[] Second, string RptTitle)
{

    iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = null;
    int numberOfPages = 0;
    int currentPageNumber = 0;
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, MemStream);
    doc.Open();
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage page = null;
    //Third, append all the PDFs--THIS IS THE MAGIC PART
    if (First != null)
    {
        reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(First);
        numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages;
        currentPageNumber = 0;
        while ((currentPageNumber < numberOfPages))
        {
            currentPageNumber += 1;
            doc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
            doc.NewPage();
            page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, currentPageNumber);
            //we know that the page would always be in Potrait Format
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 1);

        }
    }

    if (Second != null)
    {
        reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(Second);
        numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages;
        currentPageNumber = 0;
        while ((currentPageNumber < numberOfPages))
        {
            currentPageNumber += 1;
            doc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());
            //.Rotate());
            doc.NewPage();
            page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, currentPageNumber);
            //we know that the page would always be in LandScape Format
            //  cb.AddTemplate(page,0, -1f, 1f, 0,0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(currentPageNumber).Height+300);
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    doc.Close();
    byte[] cc = StringToByteArray(doc.ToString());
    return cc;
```

Comment: Please answer Paolo's question: where did you get this example? So we can track down the source of the wrong example and get it corrected or removed. Your collaboration helps improve the quality of iText.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you people get this examples, they are completely wrong.

First, use `PdfCopy`, not `PdfWriter`. That way the correct page size and orientation will be correctly imported.

Second, if your `MemStream` is a `MemoryStream` you would use `MemStream.ToArray()` to get the PDF bytes.

PS: Where did that invention of `doc.ToString()` come from? It's completely rubbish.